# Core Data FetchRequest Predicate Not Returning Correct Objects

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have an Entity with 3 attributes. One of the attributes is a string representing associated times, called `times` in the form "0,2,4,7". I created it by joining an array with ",". I want to be able to use a predicate and return only those managed objects that have a "0" in this string. I have tried the following predicates:

`NSPredicate(format: "times CONTAINS %@", 0.description)`

`NSPredicate(format: "ANY times CONTAINS %@", 0.description)`

Edit tried these as well:

`NSPredicate(format: "times CONTAINS[C] %@", "0")`

`NSPredicate(format: "times CONTAINS[CD] %@", "0")`

`NSPredicate(format: "times BEGINSWITH[CD] %@", "0,")`

`NSPredicate(format: "times BEGINSWITH %@", "0,")`

and I also verified the attribute strings being searched on and I listed the correct format above.
end Edit

but none of them has been limiting the return from Core Data. I have been getting all of the managed objects. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "times CONTAINS[C] %@", "0")` should do the trick.

Comment: No joy... while I hadn't tried [C], I didn't think a number string had a case. I also tried diacritic as well, just to see. I also tried BEGINSWITH to no effect as well.

Comment: Sorry, the `[C]` was useless, it's just by habit I want case insensitive... What is `timesDelays_` vs `times`? since it should be `NSPredicate(format: "times CONTAINS %@", "0")` Did you print the predicate, juste in case?

Comment: That should have been times. Doing too much at once. Also, I am not sure what you mean "Did you print the predicate, juste in case?"?

Comment: I mean, did you hard written `"0"`? Or did you use an intermdiary variable? Because that could change everything. So if you use `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...)`, and do `yourRequest.predicate = predicate`, `print("predicate: \(predicate)")`.

Comment: Gotcha. Currently, this is the printout from the predicate: times BEGINSWITH "0,"

Comment: And I did try with an intermediary variable earlier, and trying it again with the edits didn't work either...

Comment: I asked for printing the predicate incase you had something like."Optional()" etc. Could you print the value of your items? Like `results.forEach { print($0.times) }` to be sure? Is it a `Transformable` field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231477/discussion-between-yrb-and-larme).

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the actual code you are using - from creating the predicate, assigning it to the fetch request, executing the fetch, and printing the results: it sounds very much like the problem is not in the format string for the predicate, but elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct, it was not in the predicate itself. I ended up deterring the problem was that I was trying to use the predicate through a relationship. I switched up fetched entities and dealt with it that way. Thank you for the attempted assist.